# Catboost Python: How to interpret the MAE and R2 values

Tags: python, regression, metrics, evaluation, catboost

I have fitted a regression model using Catboost. I want to predict tax values. The target variable which I am trying to predict is:

```html
count      192687.00000
mean        94280.45840
std       1546991.34422
min       -514999.00000
25%          7159.00000
50%         19601.00000
75%         50589.50000
max     353125221.00000
Name: tax_value, dtype: float64
```

I have fitted two models. Model 1 has fewer variables than model 2:

```html
Model 1:

MSE: 2355128439744.5
MAE: 81851.6
Train r2 score:  0.26
Test r2 score:  0.23
Train RMSE : 1553001.7
Test RMSE : 1534642.7


Mode 2: 

MSE: 5374477074472.9
MAE: 110471.2
Train r2 score:  0.56
Test r2 score:  0.50
Train RMSE: 1988204.3
Test RMSE: 2318291.8
```

I can see that the R2 in model 2 is much better than in model 1. However I am unsure how to interpret the MAE values. Shouldn't the MAE in Model 2 be smaller?
I appreciate any help or input!